# The appropriateness of answers intended to clarify an OPs questions

Tags: discussion, answers

My question relates to observed behavior/etiquette that I find somewhat puzzling.

With some regularity new/low rep users post questions that are somewhat ambiguous so that it is not sufficiently clear what it is that they are asking for or trying to achieve. If it is obvious that they put some effort in the question, attempts at solving it themselves and are responsive to comments on their question by providing clarifications, I give them the benefit of the doubt.

I observe however that such questions often attract many downvoters, who choose to not contribute in other ways to improve the question or encourage the OP to improve it.

An approach I have taken a few times in such a case, is to try and infer what OP was trying to achieve, and state that as the premise of the answer. This is intended primarily to help clarify the question, in a manner that would be more difficult to achieve using a series of questions in the comments. Of course, this stated premise could turn out to be wrong.

Given the fact that such "speculative" answers also seem to attract the same set of downvoters, should I assume that this is not appropriate and refrain from posting answers intended to clarify the question?

Note that my trigger for asking this question was: [Comparing linkedlists c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152224/comparing-linkedlists-c-sharp)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, you should **not** be using answers to clarify the OPs question.

Now, that said, thats not exactly what you were doing. You thought you understood the question, and tried to answer that. Doing so is totally OK, just be prepared for downvotes if you understood incorrectly.

The biggest problem I see with your answer is that it sounds very conversational, and a bit... unsure of yourself. If you think you know the answer, say so!

One approach is to say: "To do X, use this" where X is what you think the person is asking.  Then you might get comments/downvotes if people think you answered the wrong question, but its always better to be more authoritative and less conversational/unsure when posting an answer.

In your example, toss out everything up to "list2 contains each element from a list1." and say "To check if list2 contains each element from some other list..." or something like that. Doing so doesn't guarantee no downvotes of course, but it does make it a better post.

Comment: You are right. I should have included OPs statement from the comments on which my premise was based (which I just did). That would have made my answer much less ambiguous and could have prevented some discussion.

Comment: @Alex Much better. You don't necessarily need the "in the comments" part (especially because comments are ephemeral), it would be better to just edit that part into the question. Then you can be even less ambiguous!

Comment: @Alex even if you are 100% correct in your answer, you'll still attract downvotes. Some people just believe it's wrong to try to answer a bad question and will punish you for it as a way of discouraging you. I disagree with those people.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it should be very simple: When in doubt about an OP's intent, ask him/her in a comment.

If s/he answers - you'll not waste your time answering the wrong question.  If s/he doesn't - after a while it's sort of an abandoned question and probably anything you do would be fine (including not answering at all, since the OP doesn't seem to care).